# Using split function into array is causing Compile Error: Can't Assign to array

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to use the `split()` function to split out a name based on spaces in the given name string.  When attempting to compile the code I've written below I get a Compile error: "Can't Assign to array".

I've pretty much copied the microsoft's example from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266289

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Function cleanName(position As Integer, inName As String) As String

Dim nameArray() As String
Dim outName As Variant

nameArray = Split(inName, " ")

Select Case position
    Case 1 'Titles
        outName = nameArray(0)
    Case 2 'First Name
        outName = nameArray(1)
    Case 3 'Middle Name
        outName = nameArray(2)
    Case 4 'Last Name
        outName = nameArray(3)
    Case 5 'Suffix
        outName = nameArray(4)
    Case Else
End Select

cleanName = outName

End Function
```

Comment: The article you link to is VB6, not VB.NET.  Take a look at [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you're using VBA then, from the examples at [VBA Split Function – How to Use](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/), it should be `nameArray() = Split(inName, " ")` - note the parentheses on `nameArray()`.

Comment: Using `nameArray() = Split(inName, " ")`  I still get the same error.

Comment: You code compiles and runs for me.  What version of Visual Studio and .NET are you using?

Comment: Which version of MS Access are you using?  I just pasted this code into MS Excel VBA for Office 2010 and it worked fine.  No error or warning.

Comment: This sounds like you have a broken reference. In the VBA editor go tools->references and check for missing references.

Comment: This compiles for me. If I do `?cleanName(1,"abc 123 gftr")` I get `abc`.

Comment: Does it work with `nameArray = VBA.Strings.Split(inName, " ")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm coming back to this since I've learn the answer was that my co-worker had written a module called split which kept my previous code from working as it returned a different set of parameters.